# Understanding Python's roc_curve, svm example

Tags: svm, roc

I'm trying to understand how this Python code works, conceptually, so I can write a paper about it. I have an analogous question for the random forest algorithm; but maybe if I understand this, I'll understand that too. Here's just the part that I think is relevant to my question:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from numpy import interp
statifiedFolds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
i = 1

for train,test in statifiedFolds.split(x,y):

    svc = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C = 10000, gamma = 0.1)
    x_train, x_test = x[train], x[test]
    y_train, y_test = y[train], y[test]
    svc.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = svc.decision_function(x_test)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test,y_pred)
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    i += 1

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
```

As I understand, the ROC curve plots false positive rate against true positive rate. But each time you run SVM on the testing set, you get a single binary prediction for each testing point. You then calculate the true positive rate and false positive rate by tallying true positives and false positives. So tpr should be just a single number, as should fpr. Thus (tpr,fpr) should be just a single point.

This leads me to expect that to get an roc curve, one should run the classification algorithm under many different parameters. If you're lucky, the algorithm will have a parameter such that larger values tends to benefit sensitivity at the expense of specificity, or the other way around. But neither of SVM's parameters (C and gamma) do that. So I would have thought you'd have to try many values of C and gamma until the left, middle and right regions of the roc curve are all well-represented.

But this code looks nothing like that. Only one pair of parameter values (C=10000, gamma = 0.1) ever gets called. And svm is run only once, followed by a call of an interpolation function, within each fold of the 5-fold cross-validation.

My question is: How is it possible to interpolate the roc curve using only 1 point?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in this reasoning lies in the fact that `svc.decision_function(x_test)` is *not* returning binary data.

It's actually returning a (signed) value, proportional to the distance of the samples X to the separating hyperplane. You can therefore plot a proper roc curve by adjusting the threshold around the default value of 0.

NB: See [the reference documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) for details, `svc.decision_function` will return slightly different formats depending on the `decision_function_shape` argument of `svc`.